# Set the size of a boolean array inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, tree, boolean

I'm trying to do something conceptually simple but for some reason I can't figure it out.

I'm making a tree structure (or octree in this case):

```
class Octree
{
    public readonly Octree parent;
    public Dictionary<Boolean[,,], Octree> children;
    public readonly bool[,,] index;
}
```

The Boolean array must only be [1,1,1] and the children dictionary must only contain 8 key value pairs.

I can get the 8 children fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to mandate the Boolean array to only be [1,1,1]

I've looked around and can't find an answer, it's probably so simple no one else has asked, but I'm running in circles.

I've tried making a "struct Index {bool x,y,z}" but I don't want to specify them one at a time. Then I tried to make a "class Index : Boolean[1,1,1]" but you can not inherit from the sealed Boolean class, and trying limit it to [1,1,1] like that would not work even if you could. Then I tried to make an alias "using Index = System.Boolean[,,];" but that does not work either.

I also want to make "children" sort of read only. You shouldn't be able to change the dictionary it uses, or the keys. The values of the keys you should only be able to set once, but you will not know what the those are until the children have been created. I have no idea if that is even possible.

Any help you can give me is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: _"I can't for the life of me figure out how to mandate the Boolean array to only be [1,1,1]"_ sounds to me like you'd be better off with a custom data structure?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do with a one by one by one array. Isn't that just a single `bool` value? Or did I misunderstand what you meant by `[1,1,1]`?

Comment: Your problem is that you are unintentionally creating a three dimensional array and it appears you want a single dimensional array of 3 `bool`s. But to offer you a solution, we need to understand your usage a bit better. Instead of using `true` or `false`, you refer to `1` as the value. You also refer to it as a never changing constant, which leads to why you would have a dictionary with only one key. Can you explain your situation better

Comment: I agree with the 1st comment. The question, as confusing as it is, sounds pretty much like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also have to agree. Why do you want to do this? What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: These are coordinates in a cube, you can use [3], but [1,1,1] is a location, giving you 8 locations in a cube. the 3D array is more for user interfacing than simplicity

Comment: an array declared like: `bool[,,] x = new bool[1, 1, 1];` can only hold one value, since each dimension only has one index (you can only refernence the value at `x[0,0,0]`)

Comment: To have 8 coordinates your declaration should be [2,2,2], as other pointed out [1,1,1] only gives 1 element

Comment: No to have 8 cords you need [1,1,1] they are: 1 [false,false,false] ( will use numbers form here on out), 2 [1,0,0], 3 [0,1,0,], 4 [0,0,1], 5 [1,1,0], 6 [1,1,1], 7 [0,1,1], 8 [1,0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your dictionary private and change key type - from bool array to int

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, Octree> children = new Dictionary<int, Octree>();
```

Now add a custom indexer:

```
public Octree this[bool x, bool y, bool z]
{
    get => children[GetIndex(x, y, z)];
    set => children[GetIndex(x, y, z)] = value;
}
```

Where `GetIndex` can looks like this:

```
private int GetIndex(bool x, bool y, bool z)
{
    Func<bool, int> toInt = b => b ? 1 : 0;
    return toInt(x) << 2
           | toInt(y) << 1
           | toInt(z);
}
```

Now you can use your `Octree` like

```
var root = new Octree();
root[true, false, false] = new Octree();
```

Comment: Sort of what I need, but just for the Index value, not for the children. I will try and make a custom indexer for that, and adding one for the children will be handy to. Thanks!

Comment: public struct Index
{
    bool[] index;
    public bool[] this[bool x, bool y, bool z]
    {
        get
        {
            return index;
        }
        set
        {
            index[0] = x;
            index[1] = y;
            index[2] = z;
        }
    }
}

That is kind of what I was looking for, using Index as a key limits the size indirectly, so it should work for now.